# Subtract 2 aggregated value colomns on Power Pivot using Excel 2013

Tags: excel

Please assist me with the below issue am experiencing.

I have created a PowerPivot table that shows daily students attendance per site. This shows the overall summary for Nov 2014 and Dec 2014. On the Pivottable fields, **Month** is column, **Site** is rows and **NumberOfStudent** is values. By default the grand total sum of all the values. Now what I want to achieve is instead of having grand total as sum of everything I want to show this field as a difference. **Subtracting November Numbers from December Numbers**.

I honestly thought this is one of the simple things to do but is giving me a hussle.

Below is the current and desired output

```
 Current Output                                 
 Sum of Number  Column Labels                               
 Row Labels     Nov     Dec     Grand Total                     
 Joburg         7468    7398    14866                       
 Benoni         4690    4619    9309                        
 Polokwane      1351    1399    2750                        
 Melville       4902    4887    9789                        
 Sandton        3487    3438    6925                        
 Groblersdal    746     710     1456                        
 GrandTotal     22644   22451   45095                       

 Desired Output (Need Assistance to get this)

 Sum of Number  Column Labels                       
 Row Labels     Nov     Dec     Grand Total                     
 Joburg         7468    7398    -70                     
 Benoni         4690    4619    -71                     
 Polokwane      1351    1399     48                     
 Melville       4902    4887    -15                     
 Sandton        3487    3438    -49                     
 Groblersdal    746     710     -36                     
 GrandTotal     22644   22451   -193
```

Comment: Could you revise your question to include what formulas you've already tried.  Where are the ranges you wish to include, etc.

Comment: Hi peege please have a look at the latest edit of my post I hope the recent modification helps

Comment: Yes, it helps.  What is the formula for Grand Total?

Comment: The Grand total is the default calculated total, when creating the pivot table, on the first table shows the sum of December and November Numbers. On my desired output I need it to show the difference (Numbers for December subtract Numbers for November)